# How to select a subset of rows from a subset of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this is my pandas data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                    'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                    'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                   index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

>>> df
        num_legs  num_specimen_seen  num_wings
falcon         2                 10          2
dog            4                  2          0
spider         8                  1          0
fish           0                  8          0
```

and these are the rows I need to select `row_index=[1,3]`. For a single column I can use this way

```
>>> df.num_wings[row_index]
dog     0
fish    0
```

But I want to do this in a subset of columns and not the whole dataframe like this

```
df[['num_legs','num_wings']][row_index]
```

which gives `KeyError: '[1 3] not in index'`. How can we select a subset of rows from a subset of columns in pandas dataframe?

Comment: Use `.loc()` or `iloc()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with positions by columns by names with [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
a = df.iloc[row_index, df.columns.get_indexer(['num_legs','num_wings'])]
print (a)
      num_legs  num_wings
dog          4          0
fish         0          0
```

If need `fancy indexing` convert values to numpy array:

```
#0.24+ 
a = df.to_numpy()[row_index, df.columns.get_indexer(['num_legs','num_wings'])]
#pandas below
a = df.values[row_index, df.columns.get_indexer(['num_legs','num_wings'])]
print (a)
[4 0]
```